# Three.js prevent object moving when changing pivot point after rotating the object

Tags: javascript, three.js

I've been struggling with this problem for quite some time, I guess for some of you this might be a stupid mistake but this is what's happening:
The code in the snippet works fine, you can rotate the object(image) by clicking outside of it and dragging and you can also move the pivot point and then rotate on that pivot, everything fine till here. The problem is when you already rotated the object(image) and then want to adjust the pivot, the image translate in X and Y sort of opposite to the pivot. I'll highly appreciate any help!

```js
//This is I think the most relevant part of the problem.
THREE.Object3D.prototype.updateMatrix = function () {

      this.matrix.compose( this.position, this.quaternion, this.scale );

      var pivot = this.pivot;

      if ( pivot != null ) {

          var px = pivot.x, py = pivot.y,  pz = pivot.z;
          var te = this.matrix.elements;

          te[ 12 ] += px - te[ 0 ] * px - te[ 4 ] * py - te[ 8 ] * pz;
          te[ 13 ] += py - te[ 1 ] * px - te[ 5 ] * py - te[ 9 ] * pz;
          te[ 14 ] += pz - te[ 2 ] * px - te[ 6 ] * py - te[ 10 ] * pz;

      }

      this.matrixWorldNeedsUpdate = true;

};
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
//////////////////////////////////////////////////
//  TYPICAL INITIALIZATION CODE FOR THREE.JS
//  NOTHING REALLY IMPORTANT GOING ON HERE
////////////////////////////////////////////////
  const canvas = document.querySelector('#test');
  canvas.style.height = window.innerHeight + 'px';
  canvas.style.width = window.innerWidth + 'px';

  let textureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
  const raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();

  const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({canvas: canvas, alpha: true, antialias: true});

  const scene = new THREE.Scene();
  const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );
  camera.position.z = 5;

//////////////////////////////////////////////////

  //Vectors to compare starting point and endpoint for quaternion rotation
  let pointStart = new THREE.Vector3();
  let pointEnd = new THREE.Vector3();
  
  //Adding the back plane 
  const backplaneGeo = new THREE.PlaneGeometry( 100, 100 );
  const backplaneMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0x00ff00 });
  const backplane = new THREE.Mesh( backplaneGeo, backplaneMaterial );
  backplane.position.set( 0, 0, 0 );
    
  //Adding the image plane
  const geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry( 4, 4);
  const targetMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial();
  const targetTexture = textureLoader.load( `https://i.postimg.cc/zvG7wBz1/meme-functions.jpg` );
  targetMaterial.map = targetTexture;
  const targetUi = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, targetMaterial );
  targetUi.name = "target";

  //Adding the pivot icon
  const targetCenterGeometry = new THREE.CircleGeometry( 0.2, 8 );
  const targetCenterMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial();
  const centerTexture = textureLoader.load( `http://cdn.onlinewebfonts.com/svg/img_498092.png`);
  targetCenterMaterial.map = centerTexture;
  let targetCenterMesh = new THREE.Mesh( targetCenterGeometry, targetCenterMaterial );
  targetCenterMesh.position.set( 0, 0, 0.01 );
  targetCenterMesh.name = "pivot";
  
  //This will define the pivot position
  targetUi.pivot = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0);
  
  //Just a circle to visualize the mouse position
  const mouseGeo = new THREE.CircleGeometry( 0.1, 8 );
  const mouseMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0xff0000});
  const mouseMesh = new THREE.Mesh( mouseGeo, mouseMaterial );
  
  scene.add(mouseMesh);
  scene.add(backplane);
  scene.add(targetCenterMesh);
  scene.add(targetUi);

  //Target rotation function
  const rotation = function (pos){
    pointEnd.copy( pos ).sub( targetUi.position );
    let quat = new THREE.Quaternion();
    quat.setFromUnitVectors( pointStart.clone().normalize(), pointEnd.clone().normalize() );
    targetUi.quaternion.multiply( quat );

    targetUi.rotation.x = 0;
    targetUi.rotation.y = 0;

    targetUi.updateMatrixWorld();

    pointStart.copy( pointEnd );
  }
  
  //Pivot Moving function
  const movePivot = function(pos){
    //move the pivot mesh
    targetCenterMesh.position.x = pos.x;
    targetCenterMesh.position.y = pos.y;
    //Change global mouse position to local position
    targetUi.worldToLocal(pos);
    //move pivot vector
    targetUi.pivot.x = pos.x;
    targetUi.pivot.y = pos.y;
  }
  
  //Target selection function
  let readyToRotate = false;
  const select = function(){
    let pos = raycaster.intersectObject( targetUi, true );
      if (!pos[0]) {
        readyToRotate = true;
      } else {
        readyToRotate = false;
      }
  }
  
  //Pivot selection function
  let pivotSelected = false;
  const pivotSelect = function() {
    let pos = raycaster.intersectObject( targetCenterMesh, true );
    if (pos[0]) {
      pivotSelected = true;
    } else {
      pivotSelected = false;
    }
  }
  
  //Mouse handler
  const mouse = new THREE.Vector2();
  let pivotReadyToMove = false;
  const mouseHandler = function(action) {
    event.preventDefault();
    mouse.x = (event.layerX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1;
    mouse.y = - (event.layerY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1;
    raycaster.setFromCamera( mouse.clone(), camera ); 
    let pos = raycaster.intersectObject( backplane, true );
    mouseMesh.position.set(pos[0].point.x, pos[0].point.y, 0.1);
    if (pos[0]) {
      switch (action) {
        case 'move':
          if(readyToRotate) {
            rotation(pos[0].point);
          } else if (pivotSelected) {
            movePivot(pos[0].point);
          }
          break;
        case 'mouseDown': 
          pivotSelect();
          select();
          break;
        case 'mouseUp': 
          pivotSelected = false;
          readyToRotate = false;
          break;
      }
    }
  }

  function animate() {
      requestAnimationFrame( animate );
      renderer.render( scene, camera );
  }
  animate();
  document.addEventListener('mousemove',() => {mouseHandler('move')}, false);
  document.addEventListener('mousedown',() => {mouseHandler('mouseDown')}, false);
  document.addEventListener('mouseup',() => {mouseHandler('mouseUp')}, false);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.js"></script>
<canvas id="test">
</canvas>
```

Comment: You might find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61745025/128511) useful. Changing updateMatrix is an interesting choice. You might also find [this documentation on what Maya does for a node](http://download.autodesk.com/us/maya/2010help/api/class_m_transformation_matrix.html). Rather than just `translation * rotation * scale` maya uses `translation * rotationPivotTranslation * rotationPivot * rotation * rotationOrientation * inverseRotationPivot * scalePivotTranslate * scalePivot * scaleShearing * scale * InvsersScalePivot`

Comment: All of that is to allow the scale and rotation points and be moved from the origin of the object itself. Possibly the relevant point is rather than just a adding in a pivot you need to do 3-4 operations. multiply by the inverse of the pivot (ie, move the object so the pivot becomes the origin), then rotate, then move the object back and when moving the pivot use the rotationPivotTranslation to keep the object from moving as you change the pivot

Comment: Thanks @gman I'll take a look at it. To be honest changing the updateMatrix method was also a suggestion I fund after digging a bit on how to achieve this. Maybe there are better ways but I was happy with that so far since it was working perfectly before working out quaternion rotations